# Azure Fuctions inbound connections limits

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I increase the number of simultaneous inbound connections allowed in an Azure Function App running in a Consumption Plan?

I can see that Dedicated Plans are unbounded, is there any configuration in the Azure Portal which allows to increase the threashold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concurrent execution of azure fucntion is related to specific triggers, you can refer to [parallel execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#parallel-execution):

[image]

For example:

If your function use `Http` trigger, you can use `maxConcurrentRequests`, the default value of `maxConcurrentRequests` for consumption plan is 100. You can refer to [host.json settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output#hostjson-settings):

> The maximum number of HTTP functions that are executed in parallel. This value allows you to control concurrency, which can help manage resource utilization. For example, you might have an HTTP function that uses a large number of system resources (memory/cpu/sockets) such that it causes issues when concurrency is too high. Or you might have a function that makes outbound requests to a third-party service, and those calls need to be rate limited. In these cases, applying a throttle here can help.
> *The default for a Consumption plan is 100. The default for a Dedicated plan is unbounded (-1).